# Python inbuilt (library) function for testing substring (reverse of contains)

Tags: python, syntax

I have a substring and want to check if this is present in a text. This way works:

```
sub in text
```

is there an existing (as part of Python standard library, preferable as a method of *str* class) that is equivalent to *is_part_of* in the code below:

```
# sub has to be the first parameter
def is_part_of(sub, text):
   return sub in text
```

But if there is an existing method, we could pass around the function as

```
sub.is_part_of
```

to evaluate on incoming text. So, I am looking for a cleaner version of (assume *sub* is fixed)

```
lambda text: sub in text
```

i.e. the named fucntion equivalent of `in` syntax. (with same order of parameter)

Please note that I am not looking for:

```
opertoar.contains(text, sub) # or
text.__contains__(sub)
```

The above expects sub as an argument and the text is known. In my case, sub is known/fixed but text is a parameter.

This is not a matter of functionality, but style. Or maybe, a easier way to derive/compose functions.

Comment: Use your `is_part_of` and [partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to create new functions? Cannot be used on `operator.contains` since the first args is the text and keyword args are not allowed.

Comment: Using partial is probably as good as lambda, I was looking for a more read-able intent-showing style.

Comment: Maybe a function that returns functions/lambdas? Like `def make_contains_check(sub): return lambda text: sub in text`